# Facebook post on own steam not showing

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8.1

So I'm having trouble with updating the facebook status.
Using the following code:

```
    private const string FacebookPermissions = "user_about_me,publish_stream,read_stream";

            try
            {
                dynamic fbPostTaskResult = await fbclient.PostTaskAsync("/me/feed", new { message = "" + text });
                var responseresult = (IDictionary<string, object>)fbPostTaskResult;
                fbclient.PostCompleted += fbclient_PostCompleted;
                failed = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ObjFBHelper.LoginAndContinue();
            }
```

The problem is that it's shared at all. Can only be viewed by me.
Have checked the facebook settings and it's set to friends.

[image]

Have anyone seen this before? Havent got any hits on google.

Comment: You need to flick the switch next to _“Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?”_ on the Status&Review tab in your app dashboard to “Yes” …

Comment: Oh, okay.. Thank you!  ;) 
Please give answer to receive points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flick the switch next to *“Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?”* on the Status&Review tab in your app dashboard to “Yes” …

Anything posted via an app will only be visible to the general public, if that is set. Otherwise only people with a role in the app (admin/developer/tester) will be able to see the created content.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow in settings to make it visible for other users.

[image: Check here]